# Moving background color in li hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create li hover effect in drop-down, like the following link.

http://pitch.select-themes.com/home-agency/

Like the `li` background color moving from one `li` to another `li` in dropdown in hover state.

I have tried the following

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         
 $('.menu li').hover(function(){
  $(this).children('ul').fadeIn(300);
 },
 function () {
  $(this).children('ul').fadeOut(300);        
 });
  
});
```

```css
*{
 padding:0; 
 margin:0; 
}
.menuPan{
 background-color:#b3b3b3;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5px 0;
}
.menuPan ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:0 12px 0 12px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 border-right:solid 2px #fff;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:999;
}
.menuPan ul li:last-child{
 border-right:0; 
}
.menuPan ul li a{
 color:#fff;
 display:block;
 line-height:20px;
 padding:5px 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.menuPan ul li a:hover{
 color:#d2d2d2;
}
.menuPan ul li.personalLink a:hover, 
.menuPan ul li.personalLink.current_page_item a{
 color:#c0f241;
}
.menuPan ul li.businessLink a:hover, 
.menuPan ul li.businessLink.current_page_item a{
 color:#0088ce;
}
.menuPan ul li.motorLink a:hover, 
.menuPan ul li.motorLink.current_page_item a{
 color:#7c367b;
}
.menuPan ul li ul{
 position:absolute;
 top:30px;
 left:0;
 background-color:#b3b3b3;
 text-align:left;
 display:none;

}
.menuPan ul li ul li{
 border-right:0;
 display:block;
 font-weight:600;
 border-bottom:solid 1px #c2c2c2;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.menuPan ul li ul li a{
 display:block;
 white-space:pre;
}
.menuPan ul li ul li:hover{
 background-color:#fff;
 background-color:#9f9f9f;
}
.menuPan ul li ul li:hover a{
 color:#fff; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuPan">
 <div class="container">
     <ul class="menu" id="menu-mainmenu"><li class="personalLink"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
 <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Link One</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Link Two</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Link Three</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Link Four</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Link Five</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Link Six</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="businessLink"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Link Three</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="motorLink"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I have also create a **[jsFiddle file](https://jsfiddle.net/jt65b9ec/)**

Comment: what is the problem here.?

Comment: in my code background color in dropdown li is not moving on hover, I am trying to move it like the given link

Comment: remove `border bottom` from `li` after that give transaction css `li` or `li a` where do you  want ` -webkit-transition: background-color .15s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .15s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color .15s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color .15s ease-out; ` and you no need `javascript`

Comment: So inspect the element and see what styles are applied to it, on hover state.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented the effect:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(".follow").stop().animate({
    "top": $(this).position().top
  }, 200);
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jjgtcs8b/)

Note that the CSS z-index is important, the rest of the CSS are for decoration.

Comment: this is almost near what I am trying, but I am not able to add blank "follow" li

Comment: @RoySonasish you mean u cant change the html?

Comment: its on a wordpress, I can't add blank li

Comment: @RoySonasish Did you check the code? Did u try adding `&nbsp;` instead of _blank_...?

Comment: I am trying to do this in proper way, if not success, will try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
#menu-mainmenu > li {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 1s;
}

#menu-mainmenu > li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```